# Mongo: Traverse error when updating object inside nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the `floor_num` value from `1` to `9000` in an object in a nested array, in Mongoose:

```
thingSchema.findById(thingID, function(err, lm) {
  if (!lm){
    console.log(err);
  }
  else {
      lm.update({'style.maps.localMapArray.map_marker_viewID': req.body.map_marker_viewID}, 
      {'$set': {
        'style.maps.localMapArray.$.floor_num': 9000,
      }
      }, function(err) {
        //update success
    });
  }
});
```

But I'm getting this Mongo error:

```
MongoError: cannot use the part 
   (localMapArray of style.maps.localMapArray.map_marker_viewID) to traverse
   the element ({localMapArray: [ { map_marker_viewID: "acympqswmkui", 
   floor_num: 1 } ]} code: 16837
```

My schema:

```
   var thingSchema = new Schema({
        style: {
            maps: {
                localMapArray: [{
                   map_marker_viewID : String,
                   floor_num : Number
                }],
            }
        }
   });
```

Comment: Your code should work fine. You would get the error only if you do not use the `$`(positional operator.) to update.

Comment: I agree. The update is fine. Can you double check what error you get, if any?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my noob way of solving such kind of problems. I am also new to MongoDB and Mongoose.

```
thingSchema.findById(thingID, function(err, lm) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);

    var localMaps = lm.style.maps.localMapArray;

    for (var i = 0; i < localMaps.length; i++) {
        if (lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i].map_marker_viewId == req.body.map_marker_viewID) {
            lm.style.maps.localMapArray[i].floor_num = 9000;
        }
    }

    lm.save();
});
```

I wish somewhere here can give better example with Mongoose. Hope it will help you.